# Let's encrypt error certificate install error - "Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges"

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, lets-encrypt

I got this error while renewing let's encrypt certificate:

> "Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any
>   combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA"

How can I fix this?

The command I running is like this:

```
./letsencrypt-auto --apache --renew-by-default -d <domain name>
```

Comment: Solution: sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade certbot . new upgrade resolve this issues

Answer (score 34):

It is because Let’s Encrypt has currently [disabled](https://letsencrypt.status.io/) the TLS-SNI-01 challenge due to [an identified security issue](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-09-issue-with-tls-sni-01-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/49996).

The official has provided an workaroud at the [Let's Encrypt community website](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solution-client-with-the-currently-selected-authenticator-does-not-support-any-combination-of-challenges-that-will-satisfy-the-ca/49983) as following:

If you’re serving files for that domain out of a directory on that server, you can run the following command:

```sh
sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path <path to served directory> --installer nginx -d <domain>
```

If you’re not serving files out of a directory on the server, you can temporarily stop your server while you obtain the certificate and restart it after Certbot has obtained the certificate. This would look like:

```sh
sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer nginx -d <domain> --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

### 2018-01-19 update

Let’s Encrypt just released [Certbot 0.21.0](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-0-21-0-release/50725), which use **HTTP-01**  challenge type instead of the compromised **TLS-SNI-01** by default for **apache httpd** and **nginx**. Update your certbot to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Is the "path to served directory" the nginx config? Would it look something like this: `etc/nginx/sites-available/<projectname>`

Comment: I'm on nginx, and just installed and it's giving me that error, I used sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot. How do I check version and/or update?

Comment: Okay got it working with: sudo certbot --authenticator standalone --installer nginx -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain2.com --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"

Comment: What's all that NGINX stuff about? OP is using Apache, not Nginx. - and me too

Comment: Same here.  Just replace `nginx` with `apache` for the `--installer` argument.

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me:

```
certbot --authenticator standalone --installer apache -d <domain> \
--pre-hook "systemctl stop apache2" \
--post-hook "systemctl start apache2"
```

Comment: that worked for me without the backslashes: 
`certbot --authenticator standalone --installer apache -d <domain> --pre-hook "service apache2 stop" --post-hook "service apache2 start"`

Comment: Worked without the backslashes

Comment: Backslashes are just to escape the newlines, makes the long command easier to ready.. Purely cosmetic

Answer (score 8):

Run (as root or with sudo)

```
apache2ctl stop
letsencrypt --authenticator standalone --installer apache -d your.domain
```

Choose "easy" (you can tidy up later if you want https only)

The letsencrypt agent should restart apache for you.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm using apache, I used this format,

```
sudo ./certbot-auto --authenticator webroot --webroot-path <path-to-webroot> --installer apache -d <your-domain>
```

e.g.

> sudo ./certbot-auto --authenticator webroot --webroot-path
>   /var/www/html --installer apache -d mydomain.com

Answer (score 3):

This works for ubuntu with nginx

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade certbot
certbot renew
```

Comment: In my case the certbot binary needed to be updated as well.

Answer (score 2):

**run the command and change match inside the tags <>**

```
sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --webroot-path <path to served directory> --installer apache -d <domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following commands:

```
certbot --authenticator standalone --installer apache -d <domain>
systemctl rest apache2
```